# Amazon Sagemaker: User Input data validation in Inference Endpoint

Tags: python, validation, amazon-sagemaker, endpoint, inference

I have successfully built a Sagemaker endpoint using a Tensorflow model. The pre and post processing is done inside "inference.py" which calls a handler function based on this tutorial: https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/tensorflow/using_tf.html#how-to-implement-the-pre-and-or-post-processing-handler-s

My questions are:

- Which method is good for validating user input data within inference.py?
- If such validation tests fail (e.g. wrong data types or data not in allowed range, etc.), how is it possible to return appropriate error messages with status codes to the user?
- How is this compatible with the API gateway placed above the endpoint?

Here is the structure of the inference.py with the desired validation check as a comment:

```
import json
import requests


def handler(data, context):
    """Handle request.
    Args:
        data (obj): the request data
        context (Context): an object containing request and configuration details
    Returns:
        (bytes, string): data to return to client, (optional) response content type
    """
    processed_input = _process_input(data, context)
    response = requests.post(context.rest_uri, data=processed_input)
    return _process_output(response, context)


def _process_input(data, context):
    if context.request_content_type == 'application/json':
        # pass through json (assumes it's correctly formed)
        d = data.read().decode('utf-8')
        data_dict = json.loads(data)


        # ----->   if data_dict['input_1'] > 25000:
        # ----->       return some error specific message with status code 123


        return some_preprocessing_function(data_dict)

    raise ValueError('{{"error": "unsupported content type {}"}}'.format(
        context.request_content_type or "unknown"))


def _process_output(data, context):
    if data.status_code != 200:
        raise ValueError(data.content.decode('utf-8'))

    response_content_type = context.accept_header
    prediction = data.content
    return prediction, response_content_type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer your questions inline below:

1. *Which method is good for validating user input data within inference.py?*

Seeing that you have a `handler` function, `input_handler` and `output_handler` are ignored. Thus, inside your `handler` function (as you are correctly doing) you can have the validation logic.

2. *If such validation tests fail (e.g. wrong data types or data not in allowed range, etc.), how is it possible to return appropriate error messages with status codes to the user?*

I like to think of my SageMaker endpoint as a web server. Thus, you can return any valid HTTP response code with a response message. Please see this example [inference.py](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/sagemaker_batch_transform/tensorflow_cifar-10_with_inference_script/code/inference.py#L47) file that I found as a reference.

```
_return_error(
            415, 'Unsupported content type "{}"'.format(context.request_content_type or "Unknown")
        )

def _return_error(code, message):
    raise ValueError("Error: {}, {}".format(str(code), message))
```

3. *How is this compatible with the API gateway placed above the endpoint?*

Please see this [link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/creating-a-machine-learning-powered-rest-api-with-amazon-api-gateway-mapping-templates-and-amazon-sagemaker/) for details on Creating a machine learning-powered REST API with Amazon API Gateway mapping templates and Amazon SageMaker.